# Has any country attempted to inflation adjust capital gains before taxation?

Tags: inflation, taxation

Inspired by the answer to a different question I wondered:

Can anyone think of a case study example, past or present, when capital gains are inflating adjusted before being taxed. I could imagine this making a lot of sense in high inflation currencies.

If there is an example, what prompted the introduction and was it considered a success?

Answer (score 3):

Mexico has a 3% per annum adjustment to basis on real property when calculating capital gains, though they still have a 5% floor on capital gains tax.

I cannot weigh in on the "success" of the program given everything else they're juggling.

[Source](http://yucalandia.com/living-in-yucatan-mexico/capital-gains-taxes-on-mexican-properties/)